# Will alias column take a benefit of indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume this query:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(p2.id,p1.id) id,
           COALESCE(p2.subject,p2.subject) subject,
           body
    FROM posts p1
    LEFT JOIN posts p2 ON p1.related = p2.id
    WHERE MATCH(subject,body) AGAINST(:entry)
) x INNER JOIN pivot p ON x.id = p.post_id
    INNER JOIN tags  t ON t.id = p.tag_id AND t.name = "tag_name"
```

As you  can see, `x` is a virtual table, and `x.id` is not a real column. Also `x.id` is joined to `pivot` on `pivot.post_id`. Will it take a benefit of index? If not, what's the solution?

Comment: Have you checked the explain/execution plan.

Comment: Have you tried running your query using `EXPLAIN`? That would directly answer the question

Comment: @jarlh I did, it doesn't use of any index. However not sure what kind of index should I make to be used there.